# How to Close a Window Containing a Frame, NavigationService and Timer

Tags: wpf, vb.net, window

In my project I've got a MainWindow that opens up a second Window. Inside the second Window there is a Frame and I start a navigationservice inside the Frame. Also in the second Window I've got a KeyDown method that calls Me.Close when the user presses the Escape key. Anyway, when the second Window closes a System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer() inside one of the pages in the navigation service doesn't end. Any ideas on how can I close the second Window and terminate the DispatcherTimer inside the navigationservice?

Thanks
Mike

p.s. I can supply source code if anyone wants to look at what I've got...

---

(Hey EkoostikMartin - this is a follow up to your comments..)

So I've made some progress on this. I've add:

```
 AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf Page_KeyDown
 AddHandler Me.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf Page_PreviewKeyDown
```

to the Page that has the timer. And inside the page I've defined both methods like:

```
 Private Sub Page_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.Key = Key.Escape Then
        dTimer.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Exit Page")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Page_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.Key = Key.Escape Then
            dTimer.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Exit Page")
        End If
End Sub
```

And the second Window has this:

```
  Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)

    'Escape Key Exits Program
    If e.Key = Key.Escape Then
        Me.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

So when I'm in the navigation service and navigated to the page with the Timer and I press "Esc" I get the message "Exit Page" and then the Window closes. This is good!

(I don't think I need both the KeyDown and PreviewKeyDown. When I press "Esc" I'm actually getting two "Exit Page" pop-ups)

There is a problem though: It seems like the Page doesn't get the KeyDown events unless I move the focus to a textbox or combobox and if I don't do this pressing the "Esc" key calls the second Window's Window_KeyDown and not the Page's KeyDown event which means the timer on the page doesn't get stopped even after the second Window is closed. Does anyone know a way to get the page focus when the page loads so that I can get the KeyDown event without manually changing the focus to a control on the Page?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just call the `Stop()` method on the DispatcherTimer and make sure it is disposed before closing your window?

Comment: That would work but I don't know how to catch the window closing event inside the page that has the timer... (Also, the pages in the navigationservice are created at runtime so I don't really have a way to access them from the second Window once the navigationservice starts)

Comment: Would need to see the code, specifically the code for the "second window" and the relevant bits from navigation service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I finally resolved this situation by way of a work around. In my second Window I've created a list of type DispatcherTimer:

```
Public clndTimer As New List(Of System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer)
```

I can access this list from a Page that is inside my Navigation service. Here's the code in the Page:

```
Dim dTimer As New DispatcherTimer()

dTimer.Start()

Dim wSecondWindow As New SecondWindow

wSecondWindow = Window.GetWindow(Me)

If wSecondWindow IsNot Nothing Then
    wSecondWindow.clndTimer.Add(dTimer)
End If
```

And then I capture the key event in the second Window. This is the method in the second Window:

```
 Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)

    'Escape Key Exits Program
    If e.Key = Key.Escape Then

        For Each dt In clndTimer
            dt.Stop()
        Next

        Me.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Doing it this way I don't need either the Page_KeyDown or PreviewKeyDown methods in my Page which is good because they were behaving unreliably. (see answer above)

So what do you think? I'm not totally sure about the way I get the Second window or how I check it for null in the Page but otherwise this seems to make sense.

Thanks!